# How to make pipe to grow with both sides?

Tags: math-mode, brackets, delimiters

How to make pipe (vertical bar) symbol to grow like in Dirac product notation  but without outer angle brackets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: What is the purpose/function of the vertical bar? Can you compare it to other symbols/functions? The spacing around the symbol and around the expression depends on it.

Answer (score 16):

Usually LaTeX is used with e-TeX that provides `\middle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left. a \middle| b \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The extra spaces of `\left.` and `\right.` would probably would make sense, but
they can be reduced by package `mleftright`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mleft. a \middle| b \mright.
\]
\end{document}
```

If the vertical bar is used like a relational symbol, then the spacing is achieved by

```
\left. a \mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} b \right.
```

> [image: Spacing as relational symbol]

e-TeX does not insert space between a math rel atom and the closing delimiter, the left side of `\middle`, and it does not insert space between the opening delimiter, the right side of `\middle`, and a math rel atom.

An alternative is

```
\left. a \nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\; b \right.
```

`\nonscript` suppresses the following space if in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`,
where TeX also would not set space around relational symbols.
There are differences to the previous method for punctuation characters (unlikely here),
other relational symbols (unlikely probably) and open/close delimiters, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mleft.(\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{})\mright.
\]
\[
  \mleft.(\nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\;)\mright.
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For a binary operator the space would be `\>` (medium space) instead of `\;` (thick space):

```
\mleft. a \nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\; b\mright.
```

The behaviour is a little closer to a binary operator with the following construct:

```
\left.a \mathbin{}{\nonscript\mkern-\medmuskip}\middle|{\nonscript\mkern-\medmuskip} \mathbin{} b\right.
```

> [image: Result]

Either way, it is a good idea to hide the implementation details in a markup macro.

Comment: The `\middle` command is new to me. Thanks! This is the better answer.

Comment: Adding `\;` on both sides of `|` seems better.

Comment: @egreg It depends on the purpose and function of the vertical line. `\;` is thick space, the space that is added in non-script styles if `|` would be a relational operator.

Comment: In general this "growing bar" is requested when `|` is a relation symbol. To be really picky it should be `\nonscript\;\middle|\nonscript\;`. :)

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I have added some spacing variants and some discussion to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Package [`braket`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/braket) defines some macros that can be used here.

While it defines only commands that uses angle brackets or braces (for sets), one can easily copy-edit the specification for `\Braket` to make their own `\Pipe`.

Advantages over the very similar solution of [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78570/16595) is

1. The usage of a macro.
2. You don't need to provide the `\middle` command (it is used internally) and just use plain `|` or, for double pipes, `||` and `\|`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright} % 

% the following lines are borrowed from braket
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\Pipe{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Pipe \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Pipe \endcsname#1{\begingroup
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax
       \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\let\|\BraDoubleVert
     \fi
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\BraVert
     \left.{#1}\right.\endgroup}
}

% with package mleftright:
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\mPipe{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname mPipe \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname mPipe \endcsname#1{\begingroup
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax
       \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\let\|\BraDoubleVert
     \fi
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\BraVert
     \mleft.{#1}\mright.\endgroup}
}
\begin{document}\noindent
$y  \Pipe{\dfrac{1}{2} | x_2 } z $ \\
$y \mPipe{\dfrac{1}{2} | x_2 } z $ \\
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

You can preface delimiters with `\left` and `\right` in order to have them automatically sized.
If you only have one delimiter, you can use `.` in place of the other one, as in

```
\left. \frac{1}{2} \right|
```

So if you know which side of the bar is bigger, you can try something like this:

```
\left\langle \left. \frac{1}{2} \psi_1 \right| \psi_2 \right\rangle
```

Comment: For the latter expression, using `\middle|` seems more... better.

Comment: Yes, I just learned about it. A lot of my LaTeX knowledge comes from the wikibook, which mentions `\left` and `\right` but not `\middle`. I think I'll go change that.

Comment: This was super helpful for someone with a LaTeX where \middle isn't implemented